# AVR Assembly - Operations with two 8-bit registers in 16-bit two complement negative values

Tags: avr, assembly

I have this code in which I try to multiply the given number by 4. I have two variants and that is that it is negative and positive, but it doesn't work for negative values, you don't know why?

```
.org 0
start:
    ldi r16, -120 
    ;(r21:r16) 

    ;WORK WITH  -
    cpi r16,0
    brge zaporny
    ldi r21, 0xFF 
    ;r16*4
    lsl r16
    ;kontrola overflow
    BRVC over
    dec r21
    over:
    lsl r21
    lsl r16
    BRVC over1
    dec r21
    over1:
    zaporny:
```

Comment: If it "doesn't work" what does it do then and what do you expect it to do? Why can't you use "imul"? Have you simulated what your code does and where does it go wrong, using a simulator or paper/pen or some other way?

Comment: Convention would suggest you use consecutive registers for multiple byte operations - this is to make it more obvious for us humans. 
What you want is something like this: clc,rol r16, rol r21